# Contact Layout for Front End?

Tags: profile

I'm interested in making our member directory listings more attractive, but as far as I can tell the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) only works in the Admin area. Is this correct and if so, is there an alternative to adjust layout on the public side of things?

Thanks in advance,
Barbara

Comment: is your 'listing' just a CIviCRM Profile?

Comment: What CMS are you using? Drupal or WP?